# cpSpaceHashEach - 2 problems at the same line

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I'm trying to grasp basics of Chipmunk. In some tutorial I found a line:

```
cpSpaceHashEach(space->activeShapes, &updateShape, nil);
```

But I get 2 mistakes here:

1) Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99

2) No member named 'activeShapes' in 'struct cpSpace'

What is wrong? Why doesn't it work? Do I need to include something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging into the changelog: (https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk-Physics/blob/master/VERSION.txt)

If you look, you'll find that in Chipmunk 5.x cpSpace.*Shapes were marked as private members of the cpSpace struct in the header. Then, in Chipmunk 6.x, private access was disabled by default and a cpSpaceEachShape() function appeared that almost exactly replaced cpSpaceHashEach() + cpSpace.activeShapes that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify with some code in case anyone else runs into this problem, instead of

```
cpSpaceHashEach(space->activeShapes, &updateShape, nil);
```

you'd use:

```
cpSpaceEachShape(space, &updateShape, nil);
```

Apparently this change was done so it is easier to keep the code future-proof since the activeShapes were not meant to be used in this way.